# SQLite Crash In Java Application (Online Game)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, exception

I am writing an plugin for a online game. It is running on a MS Server 2012. The plugin works by extending @EventMethods provided by the developers API and my Plugin uses a SQLite database for storing player information in relation to the games "chunks" (3D spaces within the environment).

Everything had gone fine on my test server, but I only had myself and one other user testing it.

When I deployed the plugin to the main server and people started joining (around 12 users) the server crashed after about ten minutes with a "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Now it looks to me like this was caused by SQLite crashing.

Here is an example of one of my methods that access the SQLite database.

```
@EventMethod
public void onPlayerPlaceObject(PlayerPlaceObjectEvent event) throws SQLException {

        int blockXChunk = event.getChunkPositionX();
        int blockYChunk = event.getChunkPositionY();
        int blockZChunk = event.getChunkPositionZ();

        String blockChunkID = "" + blockXChunk + blockYChunk + blockZChunk;

        try {
        //get the playerUID and the blockchunkID
        ResultSet rs  = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Areas` WHERE `PlayerUID` = '" + event.getPlayer().getUID() + "' AND `AreaID` = '" + blockChunkID + "'");

        if (rs.next() ) {
            //player owns chunk do whatever you like!
            rs.close();
            return;
        } rs.close();
        //lets see if the blockChunk event is happening somewhere where someone own ths AreaID
        rs  = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Areas` WHERE `AreaID` = '" + blockChunkID + "'" );

        if (rs.next() ) {
            //chunk is owned by someone and its not the one making the event.
            String string = (String)rs.getString("PlayerUID");
            rs.close();
            rs  = database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Friends` WHERE `OwnerUID` = '" + string + "' AND `FriendUID` = '" + event.getPlayer().getUID() + "'" );

            if (rs.next() ) {
            //player is a friend of the owner do whatever you like!
            rs.close();
            return;
        } rs.close();

            event.setCancelled(true);

            return;
        } else { rs.close(); }  


        }  catch ( Exception e ){ System.out.println(); }  
    }
```

I suspect that these methods, being called so often on the SQLite database is causing it to crash. Can someone please help me find a safer way to access this data? Or would I be better off using a "proper" database like MySQL and would that have structure in place to stop the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION ?

Edit: I have removed the reused ResultSet objects in the preceding code (naming the objects rs, rs2, rs3, etc.) but the Java Runtime Environment is still crashing with an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on an apparent random basis (I added println statements throughout the code hoping to track down where the crash was occurring - but it indeed appears random). Sometimes the server will run for 10 minutes and crash, other times it will run for 24 hours or so and then crash. I also enclosed all of the ResultSets within try-with-resources blocks. With the same outcome.

Comment: Will enclosing this in a try catch statement solve this? I don't really want to just "try it out" and have the server crash again if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reuse the ResultSet object rs for several queries, create a new instance for each query to avoid problems.